# With a regular expression, match letters and numbers but not whitespaces

Tags: regex, pcre, splunk

This is a beginner's question but I'm just getting started and need some help.

I have this string:

```
dog and cat
```

Using PCRE-Regexes, I want to match this without the whitespaces and capture it as a group, capturing`dogandcat`as $1.

I got this far `(\w*)`. Putting Parentheses outside for the capture, then read any letter, digit, or underscore. This returns
`dog`. See it here:
https://regex101.com/r/pL1bY1/3

Now I'd like to skip the adjcent whitespace and continue with `and`. How do I do that?

Comment: just enable the global flag https://regex101.com/r/pL1bY1/5. And your desired output can't be achieved by regex alone. You need some language tools to remove space present inside the first group index.

Comment: You could also replace `\s+` with an empty string to get rid of all the spaces.

Comment: Replace `/\s+/` with `//` and then match `/\w+/`.

Comment: If you're a beginner, why so specific `I want to match this without the whitespaces and capture it as a group, capturingdogandcatas $1.` ? Regex is matched left to right, when you capture in a buffer, the contents are continuous, from `dog...cat`. How can you do that without including the spaces?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski That's great but how do I replace a character using only PCRE-Regexes?

Comment: @Sam That's great but how do I replace a character using only PCRE-Regexes?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I cannot use the global flag for for intended use (configuration file in Splunk)

Comment: A regexp by itself can only match a single substring, it can't match multiple substrings and combine them.

Comment: @sln Yes this is the stated question. When using [\w]* or [\w]+ the engine stops at the first whitepace. How do I go from there? Alternatively, I could use something like .* to capture the whole line but then I don't see how to remove the whitespaces afterwards.

Comment: If you want to replace non-linebreak whitespace, use `\h+`, if you want to replace all whitespace, use `\s+`. You really don't need to approach it from the other "non-whitespace" side.

Comment: @sln That's great but how do I replace (a) character(s) using only PCRE-Regexes?

Comment: You'd use a callback to strip out the spaces. `replace( /\b\w(?:\h?\w)*\b/, function( return replace( /\h+/, "", match() ), input )`

Comment: @sln What do you mean by replace, function and return? Those are not control words of PCRE-Regex.

Answer (score 0):

In perl you can just substitute:

```
my $string = 'dog and cat';

$string =~ s/ //g;

print "$string\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have Perl availabe, only PCRE-Regexes.

Comment: @jans, PCRE means "Perl Compatible Regular Expressions". You need to add the tag of the actual language or tool you're using. Many languages support (a big part) of PCRE.

Comment: @BartKiers I would like to apply this within a Splunk transforms.conf file.